# How to handle Windows Security pop up in IE [Windows 10] using Selenium

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, webdriver

So I'm using Selenium Webdriver. On my machine running Windows 7, I can handle the Windows Security pop up using

```
driver.switchTo().alert().authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword([Credentials]));
```

But in Windows 10, I cannot. The program doesn't recognize it as an alert and just pauses until it terminates. I've tried researching similar issues but have had no luck. This is still working in IE as well, not in Edge.

Comment: Sadly the Selenium bindings are as they are, and maintainers of WebDrivers have the final say over how their driver communicates with the selenium api. Microsoft maintains the Edge driver, you may want to make an inquiry on MSDN.

Comment: @user2283704 provide more info: 1. What are your exact testing steps? 2. What worked for you? Show code. 3. Where are you stuck. 4. Provide error stacktrace. 5. provide relevant HTML DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Raj's answer but you don't need to use the Sikuli framework.  You can use the java.awt.Robot to send keystrokes to the Windows security popup.  In the example below the robot is keying a user ID of "U", then tabbing to the password box, keying a password of "P", and keying the Enter key to close the popup.

```
   Robot robot = new Robot();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    try{
        driver.get("URL");
    } catch (TimeoutException e){
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_U);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    }
```

Hope It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have work around, might be helpful here. Let me make some comments:

1. Selenium does not have capacity to handle IE "Windows Security" pop up. 
Not even through "switch alert accept/ dismiss" concept. 

2. You have to use third party tools such as AutoIT, this is what I used to handle IE pop up. But this tool has some limitations such as you can not lock you automation machine so you have to keep you test machine unlocked while test is in progress because of security reason (you can google it about).

3. Currently you can not even lock you machine while running IE Selenium Automation  

Work around is here : 

you may follow this link : http://learn-automation.com/handle-windows-authentication-using-selenium-webdriver/
```

watch video here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=civzNtKTCD0&t=862s

```
1. Download AutoIT 

2. Write up script using AutoIT editor 

3. should like this for IE scenario:



     WinWaitActive("Windows Security")
        Send("username")
        Send("{TAB}")
        Send("password")
        Send("{TAB}")
        Send("{TAB}")
        Send("{ENTER}")

        4. Save it and right click -> compile it using 64 bit 

        5. now you will have a one exe , which can be used directly in your selenium code , for example : 

driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(DrivePath);
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Users\source\HandleAuthentication.exe"); driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following strategy works for me along with thee IE Security settings

```
`UserAndPassword UC = new UserAndPassword(userName, password);
driver.switchTo().alert().authenticateUsing(UC);`
```

Comment: Try to explain more clearly why this is an answer to the question.

Comment: First we need to import import org.openqa.selenium.security.UserAndPassword; 

I Invoke the browser and Loaded the URL as usual.

Using above code I am able to pass the Username and Password

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled initially with Windows Security Alert in Windows 10 IE 11. I tried using AutoIT (not able to identify the alert but can work with Tab press), SwitchToAlert, AuthenticateUsing, Passing UID and PWD in URL etc, but they didn't work for me. At last, using Sikuli in Selenium worked. Below is the code snippet:

```
Screen s=new Screen();
//If you need to pass UID please add one more line of code here. For me only PWD field to fill.
s.type("PasswordField.png","Password");
s.find("Ok.png");
s.click("Ok.png);
```

If your application keeps loading until credentials are entered then you will get a  `pageLoadTimeout` exception before executing the Sikuli scripts. To overcome this exception I tried the below code and it works:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
try{
driver.get("URL");
} catch (TimeoutException e){
Screen s=new Screen();
s.type("PasswordField.png","Password");
s.find("Ok.png");
s.click("Ok.png);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I was able to solve the IE Basic Auth Problem in IE 11 (Windows 10) by making registry changes. As described in [this blog post](https://blog.ham1.co.uk/2016/03/05/selenium-allow-basic-auth-in-ie11/), `iexplore.exe` and `explorer.exe` keys need to be created in the following locations:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE`

They should be `DWORD` values, set to 0.

This will allow you to do:

```
http://domain%5Cuser:password@example.com
```

where `%5C` is `\`.